# angular table multiple sticky header

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sticky

how do we adjust the code so that we can make multiple sticky headers , I want to make the first column which is Name and second column which is No sticky and then the last column sticky. Currently the last and first column is sticky but the No column is not. How do we solve that ?

https://stackblitz.com/angular/nneoarrlekb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.ts

#ts code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-sticky-columns-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-sticky-columns-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-sticky-columns-example.html',
})
export class TableStickyColumnsExample {
  displayedColumns =
      ['name', 'position', 'weight', 'symbol', 'position', 'weight', 'symbol', 'star'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];
```

#html code

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position" >
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Star Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="star" stickyEnd>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>


<!-- Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```

Answer (score 2):

I just added sticky for the position column and it worked fine!

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position" sticky>
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

---

css for elevated column

```
.shaded-table thead tr > th:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px #aaaaaa;
}

.shaded-table tbody tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px #aaaaaa;
}

.shaded-table thead tr > th:nth-child(7) {
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 3px #aaa;
}

.shaded-table tbody tr > td:nth-child(7) {
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 3px #aaa;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dytr9x?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.css,src%2Fstyles.scss)

Comment: how do we add elevation like this one ? https://imgur.com/a/wqfMzxQ elavation to the sticky headers

Answer (score 1):

Multiple sticky are troubling if the are not cascading which is what you need. This is because the first column is at `left:0` and last column is at `right:0`

You can fix the width of first column say around 200px then you can add a css

```css
.mat-column-position{
  position: sticky;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: inherit; 
}
```

Unfortunately the requirement of position left/top in making a sticky div should be rethought of. I have such a requirement where I programatically calculate the width of previous column and attach the left to next element to sticky

Comment: how do we solve this lines Sir ? like the line on the first column should show and the line should be on the column position since those 2 columns are sticky

https://imgur.com/a/tVc1yok

Comment: how do we add backshadow to the position column ?